# humor phrase meaning "I enjoy making my life harder"

Tags: phrase-requests

How can one make some humour by the following Q/A pair,

Q: Cosa fai nella vita?     ===>  what do you do ?

A: Me la complico           ===>  ?  (I enjoy making my life harder)

Comment: Is your question about a general term for such an ironic, self-deprecating sentence, or about a suitable equivalent of the Italian example?

Comment: @Mari-Lou A - surely this is one for you?

Comment: Remember if you're asking how to translate the Italian that's off-topic for this site.

Comment: I didn't see this question nor medica's comment. For "Q" I'd say: *What do you do for a living?/ (literally) What do you do in life?* For "A" I'd say: *Just making it more difficult for myself* OR *Making my life more complicated/tougher than what it already is*. In Italian it sounds better:)

Comment: thanks for your replies. Every little contribute makes life more pleasant ^^.   I didnt know how to make the best translation for the quoted phrase

Comment: Could you select an answer @Violetshark? Or supply your own answer that you chose?

Answer (score 1):

Part of the wit comes with adding *in life* to the first line:

> Cosa fai nella vita?  What do you do in life?

A: Me la complico. I complicate it. (if my translation is correct)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by irony, but someone who likes making their life harder would be called a **masochist**.

Comment: Often italian and english humour don't match, so my intention has been the one to make translation as good as possible. I cannot make out how come I ve got a negative score. There are noinsultes. Thanks anyway =)

Answer (score 0):

An English idiom that you could use is:

**"be a glutton for punishment"**

> to be someone who seems to enjoy doing something that you consider unpleasant: *He's a real glutton for punishment, taking on all that extra work without getting paid for it.*

Source: [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/be-a-glutton-for-punishment)